# Columns with list of keys and values to columns with lists of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this in `pandas`:

```
  Key  Level       Subkeys     Values
0   A      0      [A1, A2]     [3, 4]
1   B      1          [B1]        [2]
2   C      2  [C1, C2, C3]  [8, 5, 1]
```

and I want to transform it to this:

```
  Key  Level                       Subdicts 
0   A      0              [{A1: 3, {A2: 4}]
1   B      1                       [{B1: 2]
2   C      2    [{C1: 8}, {C2: 5}, {C3: 1}]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: I gag every time I see pandas being used for wretched object stuff like this. Pandas is not suited to working with data it cannot vectorize. You're better off using lists and loop that iterate over those lists. Stuff like this needs ugly apply calls and list comprehensions to even work, and on top of that you have the headache of NaNs which makes everything worse.

Comment: this doesn't look very pleasant, if you explain why would you need to do it, there might be a better way ?

Comment: `[[dict(zip(x, y))] for x, y in zip(df.Subkeys, df.Values)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I agree with [cs95](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497810/columns-with-list-of-keys-and-values-to-columns-with-lists-of-dicts#comment99584565_56497810)

This is pretty gross...

```
df.assign(Subdicts=[[{x: y} for x, y in zip(X, Y)] for X, Y in zip(df.Subkeys, df.Values)])

  Key  Level       Subkeys     Values                           Subdicts
0   A      0      [A1, A2]     [3, 4]             [{'A1': 3}, {'A2': 4}]
1   B      1          [B1]        [2]                        [{'B1': 2}]
2   C      2  [C1, C2, C3]  [8, 5, 1]  [{'C1': 8}, {'C2': 5}, {'C3': 1}]
```